# my code is returning "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'style')"

Tags: javascript, html

I have different sections on wordpress and i want to show one pressing it respective button. the button "red" opens the "red section" and the other colors disappear, and goes along.

this is the code i made, it's "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'style')", can you help me?

```js
/*gets the section ids*/
var vermelho = document.getElementById("vermelho");
var laranja = document.getElementById("laranja");
var amarelo = document.getElementById("amarelo");
var verde = document.getElementById("verde");
  
  /*-----------------*/

window.trocaVermelho = function(){
  if (vermelho.style.display === "none") {
    vermelho.style.display = "block";
    laranja.style.display = "none";
    amarelo.style.display = "none";
    verde.style.display = "none";

} else{
    vermelho.style.display = "block";
}
}
function trocaLaranja(){
  
  if (laranja.style.display === "none") {
    vermelho.style.display = "none";
    laranja.style.display = "block";
    amarelo.style.display = "none";
    verde.style.display = "none";
  } else {
    laranja.style.display = "block";
  }
}

function trocaAmarelo(){
  
 
  if (amarelo.style.display === "none") {
     vermelho.style.display = "none";
    laranja.style.display = "none";
    amarelo.style.display = "block";
    verde.style.display = "none";
  } else {
   amarelo.style.display = "block";
  }
}

function trocaVerde(){
   
  
  if (verde.style.display === "none") {
    verde.style.display = "block";
  } else {
    verde.style.display = "none";
  }
}
```

```html
<ul>
    <li><button id="buttonvermelho" onclick="trocaVermelho()">a</button></li>
     <li><button id="buttonlaranja" onclick="trocaLaranja()">b</button></li>
     <li><button id="buttonamarelo" onclick="trocaAmarelo()">c</button></li>
     <li><button id="buttonverde" onclick="trocaVerde()">d</button></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

It was a typo you added a button prefix to every id which caused the error as the script was looking for `abc` not `buttonabc` .. Check solution

HTML =>

```
<ul>
  <li>
    <button id="vermelho" onclick="trocaVermelho()">Button 1</button>
  </li>
  <li>
    <button id="laranja" onclick="trocaLaranja()">Button 2</button>
  </li>
  <li>
    <button id="amarelo" onclick="trocaAmarelo()">Button 3</button>
  </li>

  <li>
    <button id="verde" onclick="trocaVerde()">Button 4</button>
  </li>

</ul>
```

Js =>

```
  /*gets the section ids*/
  const vermelho = document.getElementById("vermelho");
  const laranja = document.getElementById("laranja");
  const amarelo = document.getElementById("amarelo");
  const verde = document.getElementById("verde");

  /*-----------------*/

  const trocaVermelho = (e) => {

    if (vermelho.style.display === "none") {
      vermelho.style.display = "block"; laranja.style.display = "none"; amarelo.style.display = "none"; verde.style.display = "none";
    } else {
      vermelho.style.display = "block";
    }
  }



  function trocaLaranja() {
    if (laranja.style.display === "none") {
      vermelho.style.display = "none"; laranja.style.display = "block"; amarelo.style.display = "none"; verde.style.display = "none";
    } else {
      laranja.style.display = "block";
    }
  }


  function trocaAmarelo() {
    // try using this  function to get styles initially ! getComputedStyle(amarelo).display


    if (amarelo.style.display === "none") {
      vermelho.style.display = "none"; laranja.style.display = "none"; amarelo.style.display = "block"; verde.style.display = "none";
    } else {
      amarelo.style.display = "block";
    }
  }

  function trocaVerde() {
    if (verde.style.display === "none") {
      verde.style.display = "block";
    } else {
      verde.style.display = "none";
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your buttons ids don't match ones you use in `getElementById` method.

```
var vermelho = document.getElementById("vermelho");

<li><button id="buttonvermelho" onclick="trocaVermelho()"></button></li>
```

`vermelho` is not the same as `buttonvermelho`

---

EDIT:

Also, if your `js` script is included into your `.html` file before the elements you're trying to reach, then you're trying to reach not existing elements.

Please include your JS into HTML after the elements.

Comment: `vermelho` is the section ID, not the button.

Comment: Hmm...
Then please tell me if you use `<script></script>` tag to include your js code before the document body?

Comment: yess! i did, and it shows an error as well

Comment: Please check the edit section of my answer

Comment: Have you solved the problem yet?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```js
var vermelho = document.getElementById("vermelho");
var laranja = document.getElementById("laranja");
var amarelo = document.getElementById("amarelo");
var verde = document.getElementById("verde");
  
  /*-----------------*/

function trocaVermelho(){
  if (vermelho.style.display === "none") {
    vermelho.style.display = "block";
    laranja.style.display = "none";
    amarelo.style.display = "none";
    verde.style.display = "none";

} else{
    vermelho.style.display = "block";
}
}
function trocaLaranja(){
  
  if (laranja.style.display === "none") {
    vermelho.style.display = "none";
    laranja.style.display = "block";
    amarelo.style.display = "none";
    verde.style.display = "none";
  } else {
    laranja.style.display = "block";
  }
}

function trocaAmarelo(){
  
 
  if (amarelo.style.display === "none") {
     vermelho.style.display = "none";
    laranja.style.display = "none";
    amarelo.style.display = "block";
    verde.style.display = "none";
  } else {
   amarelo.style.display = "block";
  }
}

function trocaVerde(){
   
  
  if (verde.style.display === "none") {
    verde.style.display = "block";
  } else {
    verde.style.display = "none";
  }
}
```

```html
<html>
<ul>
  <li id="vermelho" style="display:none">vermelho </li>
  <li id="laranja"  style="display:none">laranja </li>
  <li id="amarelo"  style="display:none">amarelo </li>
  <li id="verde"  style="display:block">verde</li>
</ul>
    <button id="buttonvermelho" onclick="trocaVermelho()">trocaVermelho</button>
     <button id="buttonlaranja" onclick="trocaLaranja()">trocaLaranja</button>
     <button id="buttonamarelo" onclick="trocaAmarelo()">trocaAmarelo</button>
     <button id="buttonverde" onclick="trocaVerde()">trocaVerde</button>

</html>
```